# Call from Database to display the questions and answers

Tags: php, sql, database

I have been wanting to display the questions and answer as from the database and display them like a normal questionnaire.

However, I am only able to display the last row. Any changes of the codes needed?

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); $i++) {
        $question = $row['question'];
        $option1 = $row['option1'];
        $option2 = $row['option2'];
        $option3 = $row['option3'];
        ?>

        <?php echo $question ?> <br>
        <input type="radio" name="$i" value="$option1"><?php echo $option1 ?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="$i" value="$option2"><?php echo $option2 ?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="$i" value="$option3"><?php echo $option3 ?><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a while loop:

```
    <?php
    $count = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $count++;
        $question = $row['question'];
        $option1 = $row['option1'];
        $option2 = $row['option2'];
        $option3 = $row['option3'];
        ?>
        <?=$question?><br />
        <input type="radio" name="<?=$count?>" value="<?=$option1?>"><?=$option1?><br />
        <input type="radio" name="<?=$count?>" value="<?=$option2?>"><?=$option2?><br />
        <input type="radio" name="<?=$count?>" value="<?=$option3?>"><?=$option3?><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: My previous can be solved. There were some problems trying to connect to the database.